# play 2.0 form date validation fail

Tags: validation, date, model, playframework-2.0

I'm using "Play 2.0"-Framework (v. 2.0.1) and running into some troubles with form validation of a date value.

Peace of my Model code:

```
@Entity
public class Appointment extends Model {
    public Date start;

    public Date end;
}
```

Peace of my template code:

```
<input type="text" id="start" name="start" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" />

<!-- ALSO tested with chrome beta v. 20 with html5 support-->
<input type="date" id="end" name="end" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" />
```

My Controller:

```
public class Appointment extends Controller {
    static Form<Appointment> appointmentForm = form(Appointment.class);

    //on calling form page
    public static Result create() {
        return ok(create.render("create", appointmentForm));
    }

    //called on saving form data
    public static Result save() {
        Form<Appointment> filledForm = appointmentForm.bindFromRequest();
        if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(
                    create.render("create", filledForm)
            );
        } else {
            Appointment.create(filledForm.get());
            return redirect(routes.Appointment.index());
        }
    }
}
```

If I select a date via jquery ui datepicker or type in myself in a format like "yyyy-mm-dd" or doesn't matter, but must be correct format I run into a validation error in my controller save()-method with the check "filledForm.hasErrors()" and the error message "wrong date format".

I thought it would be converted automatically from play, so that I don't have to add a convertion by my self. What can I do to solve this problem? Is it still an issue from play 2.0?

Thanky you.

Cheers,

Marco

Answer (score 0):

I think you must define the format of the date. See [Play Framework 2.0: Custom formatters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939741/play-framework-2-0-custom-formatters) for custom formatters. Perhaps a custom binder is necessary see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/Xi2xAiCnINs/discussion 
Just as some hints to give you a direction. Hopefully someone can give you a better answer.