# Deserializing from JSON back to joda DateTime in Play 2.0

Tags: json, playframework, deserialization, playframework-2.0, jodatime

I can't figure out the magic words to allow posting JSON for a DateTime field in my app. When queried, `DateTime`s are returned as microseconds since the epoch. When I try to post in that format though (`{"started":"1341006642000","task":{"id":1}}`), I get "Invalid value: started".

I also tried adding `@play.data.format.Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` to the `started` field and posting `{"started":"2012-07-02 09:24:45","task":{"id":1}}` which had the same result.

The controller method is:

```
@BodyParser.Of(play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result create(Long task_id) {
    Form<Run> runForm = form(Run.class).bindFromRequest();
    for (String key : runForm.data().keySet()) {
        System.err.println(key + " => " + runForm.apply(key).value() + "\n");
    } 
    if (runForm.hasErrors())
        return badRequest(runForm.errorsAsJson());

    Run run = runForm.get();
    run.task = Task.find.byId(task_id);
    run.save();

    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    result.put("id", run.id);

    return ok(result);
}
```

I can also see from the output that the values are being received correctly. Anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the "Register a custom DataBinder" section of the [Handling form submission](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaForms) page along with the [Application global settings](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal) page and comparing with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939741/play-framework-2-0-custom-formatters/11297337#11297337) I came up with the following solution:

I created a custom annotation with an *optional* format attribute:

```
package models;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@play.data.Form.Display(name = "format.joda.datetime", attributes = { "format" })
public @interface JodaDateTime {
    String format() default "";
}
```

and registered a custom formatter from `onStart`:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;

import play.*;
import play.data.format.Formatters;


public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        Formatters.register(DateTime.class, new Formatters.AnnotationFormatter<models.JodaDateTime,DateTime>() {
                @Override
                public DateTime parse(models.JodaDateTime annotation, String input, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
                    if (input == null || input.trim().isEmpty())
                        return null;

                    if (annotation.format().isEmpty())
                        return new DateTime(Long.parseLong(input));
                    else
                        return DateTimeFormat.forPattern(annotation.format()).withLocale(locale).parseDateTime(input);
                }

                @Override
                public String print(models.JodaDateTime annotation, DateTime time, Locale locale) {
                    if (time == null)
                        return null;

                    if (annotation.format().isEmpty())
                        return time.getMillis() + "";
                    else
                        return time.toString(annotation.format(), locale);
                }

        });
    }

}
```

You can specify a format if you want, or it will use milliseconds since the epoch by default. I was hoping there would be a simpler way since Joda is included with the Play distribution, but this got things working.

*Note: you'll need to restart your Play app as it doesn't seem to detect changes to the `Global` class.*